# Portability check with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to determine if a number is portable to the Twilio platform.
Other providers have portability/eligibility APIs that I can use for this purpose, but I can't seem to find anything equivalent for Twilio.

Am I missing something? How can I check if a number is portable to Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio doesn't offer an API or page where users can check this currently (although this is under investigation). The best approach today is opening a support ticket with the porting team to verify portability.